# How to manually send a Devise email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, devise

I want to manually send a Devise confirmation email to a user of my app. Like this:

```
u = User.last
Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions u
```

but Devise's `confirmation_instructions` takes three parameters, the second being a token (according to the documentation) and the third being a Hash. How do I get it in order to be able to send these emails?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here’s where the [`ConfirmationsController` sends the email](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L9):

```
self.resource = resource_class.send_confirmation_instructions(resource_params)
```

Have you tried this?

```
u.send_confirmation_instructions
```

**EDIT** to add `Devise::Mailer`-based method:

```
u.send(:generate_confirmation_token)
Devise::Mailer.confirmation_instructions(u, u.instance_variable_get(:@raw_confirmation_token))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do wanna send the email by actually calling the `confirmation_instructions` method from `Devise::Mailer`

Comment: Why? And if so, why not just do what `send_confirmation_instructions` does?

Comment: Buck, that's because I want to see these emails through Rails 4.1 mailer previews, and AFAIK calling the method is the only way

Comment: Okay, I updated the answer with some hackery that should accomplish that.